# autheticate.fail not able to redirect to unauthorize asp.net core authentication

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, windows-authentication

Enabled windows authentication in my application

the below is my handler code

```
public class BasicAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
    {
        private readonly IUser _userService;
        public BasicAuthenticationHandler(IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options,
            ILoggerFactory logger,
            UrlEncoder encoder,
            ISystemClock clock,
            IUser UserService
            ) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
        {
            _userService = UserService;
        }
        protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
        {
            var a = Request.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

            User user = null;
            user = await _userService.IsAuthenicated(a, "");
            // Context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
            // Context.res = new RedirectToActionResult("Index", "Home", null);
            //Context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;

            if (user == null)
            {

                return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Invalid Username or Password");
            }
            var claims = new[] {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,user.UserName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
            };

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Scheme.Name);
            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, Scheme.Name);


            return AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);
        }
    }
```

autheticateresult.fail make a loop ask for windows credential and not redirect to custom error page.
while i tried with anomyouns its working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> autheticateresult.fail make a loop ask for windows credential and not
>   redirect to custom error page

When calling `AuthenticateResult.Fail`, it will make the `Windows Authentication` fail, and the IIS will check the authenticaiton for loop.

For a workaround, you could try `UseStatusCodePages` to rediect to error page,

```
        app.UseStatusCodePages(async context => {
            if (context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == 401)
            {
                // your redirect
                context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error");
            }
        });
        app.UseAuthentication();
```

For another option, you could custom `HandleChallengeAsync` for `BasicAuthenticationHandler`.

```
public class BasicAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
{
    public BasicAuthenticationHandler(IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options,
        ILoggerFactory logger,
        UrlEncoder encoder,
        ISystemClock clock
        ) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
    }
    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Invalid Username or Password");
    }

    protected override Task HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
    {
        Context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error");// redirect to your error page
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: after return AuthenticateResult.Fail
Does not hit the HandleChallengeAsync is their something i missed?
@Tao Zhou

Comment: @AnkitMittalLearner Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? For `HandleChallengeAsync`, it will be hit when you access a resource with `        [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "BasicAuthentication")]` and throw fault in `HandleAuthenticateAsync`, if you access a resource is not secured with `Authorize`, it will not hit `HandleChallengeAsync` even if you throw `Fail`.

Comment: thanks its working i will also test it in success condition.